# Cant open the designer on a new project after a new install

Tags: c#, designer

I installed Visual Studio 2019 Community completly new today and wanted to make a simple form. To do so I created a new "Windows Forms App (.NET Core)" in C#. 
The problem is that I cant open the Designer. If I try to it always takes me to the code editor which just shows me the code editor with the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Tic
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    }
}
```

I have already tried uninstalling installing and making a few new projects. Always the same problem. I didnt alter any code.

Comment: Use `Shift+F7` to view the designer.

Comment: For Core you need a plugin.-

Answer (score 0):

Most recent update on the same was listed in the designer release note. Try installing the windowsformdesigner setup, and can be found [here](https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/tree/master/Documentation/designer-releases)